# How to integrate FxCop into Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, fxcop

I use VS2005 but the version is not integrated to fxcop. Now I need to have some code metrics and the most proper is fxcop. How can I integrate VS with fxcop? Which version of fxcop do I need? What else should I take under consideration before I integrate fxcop?

Thanks,
Sun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is to run FxCop as an external tool. See here for details:

http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2007/02/18/106630.aspx

You should be able to use the latest version of FxCop, if you want to.